# installing a shared object without root privileges

Tags: object, makefile, root, shared

I made the makefile below:

```
CC = gcc

CCFLAGS = -Wall -L. -lall -ldl -g

LIBFLAGS = -shared -fPIC -Wall

SRC = tema4.c

PROGRAM = allocator

LIB = liball.so

LIBSRC = liballoc.c

build: 

gcc -fPIC -c liballoc.c

ld -shared -soname liball.so.1 -o liball.so.1.0 -lc liballoc.o

ldconfig -v -n .

ln -sf liball.so.1 liball.so

$(CC) -o $(PROGRAM) $(SRC) $(CCFLAGS)

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

run:

    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.

    ./allocator

clean:
rm -f $(PROGRAM) core *~
```

I run the command make and then I try to run the program but it seems it cannot open shared object liball.so (no such file or directory)

I am working on ubuntu 11.10 and I have no root privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the last part:

```
run:
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./allocator
```

Alternately:

```
run:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.; \
        ./allocator
```

The problem is that when you have multiple lines of commands for a target, make runs each line in its own shell.  So environment vars set on one line (in one shell) don't get inherited by the shells run for other lines.  The solution is to put it all on one line (so it goes to one instance of a shell), either by writing the command as a single line or use line continuations.